# Extracting text from HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code and I want in javascript to extract the username and password to make some sort of login verification. How can I do that?
Edit: I am using a node js server to extract some data, but is has nothing to do with the login page I want to do. I am trying to make a login and when the user presses the button to login it ill verify if the password and username matches (login verif) and if it foes it goes to the menu if it doesnt, gives an error.

```
<div id="login" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-theme="a" data-position="left" data-display="reveal">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="h">
            <li>
                <a href="#menu" > Menu</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#register" >Register</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#cart" > Cart</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#account" > Account</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#login" > Login</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /panel -->

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed">
        <a href="#mypanel" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-corners="false"></a>
        <h1>Log In</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

        <!-- username -->
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input id="username" title="Must be at least 8 characters."/>
        <br />

        <!-- password -->
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="password" type="password" title="title it hard to guess." />
        <br />

        <p>
            <button type="button" title="This button won't do anything">
                Proceed
            </button>
        </p>

        <label for="register">Don't have an account?</label>
        </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#register">Register</a>
    </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: ***NEVER*** do validation on the client side!

Comment: What do you mean by login verification? Assuring that the text conforms to your requirements? Or comparing it against a db?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "login verification"? Are you looking to restrict the fields to certain characters/length? Or do you want to check if it's a valid username/password combo?

Comment: **NEVER** do validation **ONLY** on the client side! :)

Answer (score 0):

So you basically want to read text values entered by the user in login and password inputs? Take a look at this: [JavaScript: how to get value of text input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-get-input-text-value)

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). If you want to make a comment (or a Close As Duplicate vote) then you should earn enough reputation before doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getElementByID()` and `value` to load the input into JS like so:

```
document.getElementById('password').value;
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: It could, but I need to write the JS on another file. It cant be on the html page. Would that also woro?

Comment: I think we need some more information. Do you mean "write" the name and password to another file, or check it against a list of valid names and passwords?